# Why does Object both include Kernel and inherit off it in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby (1.8.X)

Why does Object both inherit off Kernel and include it? Wouldn't just inheriting be enough?

```
irb(main):006:0> Object.ancestors
=> [Object, Kernel]
irb(main):005:0> Object.included_modules
=> [Kernel]
irb(main):011:0> Object.superclass
=> nil
```

Note in Ruby 1.9 the situation is similar (but a bit cleaner):

```
irb(main):001:0> Object.ancestors
=> [Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
irb(main):002:0> Object.included_modules
=> [Kernel]
irb(main):011:0> Object.superclass
=> BasicObject
irb(main):011:0> BasicObject.superclass
=> nil
irb(main):011:0> BasicObject.included_modules
=> []
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Object` does not inherit from `Kernel`, it is the final superclass (in Ruby 1.8). The result of the [`#ancestors`](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#M000790) method comprises of superclasses *and* included modules. Specifically, in the order they are looked up for any particular call.

Comment: bottom line, ancestors and superclass are not to be confused

Answer (score 5):

When you include a module in a class it becomes part of its inheritance hierarchy.  Therefore the by including Kernel Object.ancestors will include (no pun intended) Kernel.  In ruby versions < 1.9 Object is at the top of the hierarchy so it has no superclass